# NoClassDefFoundError when using java impl of leveldb

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, leveldb

for those who've managed to use this java implementation of leveldb https://github.com/dain/leveldb/

I'm getting the following stacktrace when I try to execute the code in the readme:

NoClassDefFoundError occurs when runing the following line:

DB db = factory.open(new File("example"), options);

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
at org.iq80.leveldb.impl.DbImpl.(DbImpl.java:95)
at org.iq80.leveldb.impl.Iq80DBFactory.open(Iq80DBFactory.java:59)
at com.test.LevelDBDain.main(LevelDBDain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I confirmed that `new File("example")` returns a non-null value; same as the variable `options`

I import two jars built from the source into my library:

```
1.leveldb-api.jar
2.leveldb.jar
```

I've tried this with releases 0.6, 0.7 and 0.8-SNAPSHOT and always get the same error.

Could it be something I'm doing wrong ...or missing?

Comment: Did you build the jars yourself? If so, did you verify using a zip-viewer that the classes you're expecting are in the jar archives? Did you confirm they are on your classpath? `new File("example")` will return non-null if there is a valid file path argument for potentially creating a file. It doesn't actually create the file until it's written to, so that tells you nothing. The error is telling you it can't find a package for a particular usage of `Lists`, provided by a Google package. Do you have all necessary dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I built the jars myself; thanks for the pointer @RyanJ. The error is at an implementation of a static import for of a newArraylist function: `private final List<Long> pendingOutputs = newArrayList();`. The import `import static com.google.commons.collect.Lists.newArrayList;` is a dependency of the project from the guava16 library. The concerned class which seems not to be found (com.google.common.collect.Lists) also seems to be present ...together with the static function `newArrayList()` in it. Could there be a way that the build path is somehow skipping the import during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.common.collect.util` from [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is a dependency of the leveldb library but for some reason adding it explicitly as a dependency for my java project solved the problem.